# Get Edge Data from the tidygraph package

Tags: r, tidygraph

It should be very simple, but I am stuck in this operation. I am interested in extracting the block Edge Data: 23,502 x 3. And to indicate the names of the nodes. In short, I need to know the weight of each pair of nodes by their names.

Code:

```
# A tbl_graph: 11539 nodes and 23502 edges
#
# An undirected simple graph with 2493 components
#
# Node Data: 11,539 x 3 (active)
  name            neighbors groups
  <chr>               <dbl>  <int>
1 CHANSATITPORN N         1   1540
2 POBKEEREE V             1   1540
3 SAINIS G                4    361
4 HARITOS G               4    361
5 KRIEMADIS T             4    361
6 PAPASOLOMOU I           3    361
# … with 11,533 more rows
#
# Edge Data: 23,502 x 3
   from    to weight
  <int> <int>  <dbl>
1     1     2      1
2     3     4      2
3     3     5      2
# … with 23,499 more rows
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can extract the edge information using `data.frame()` on just the edges. You can replace the example tidygraph object I've named `tg` with your tidygraph object name and the code below should work for you.

```r
library(igraph)
library(tidygraph)
library(tibble)

# https://tidygraph.data-imaginist.com/reference/tbl_graph.html
rstat_nodes <- data.frame(name = c("Hadley", "David", "Romain", "Julia"))
rstat_edges <- data.frame(from = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
                          to = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3),
                          weight = c(1:9))
tg <- tbl_graph(nodes = rstat_nodes, edges = rstat_edges)
tg
#> # A tbl_graph: 4 nodes and 9 edges
#> #
#> # A directed simple graph with 1 component
#> #
#> # Node Data: 4 x 1 (active)
#>   name  
#>   <fct> 
#> 1 Hadley
#> 2 David 
#> 3 Romain
#> 4 Julia 
#> #
#> # Edge Data: 9 x 3
#>    from    to weight
#>   <int> <int>  <int>
#> 1     1     2      1
#> 2     1     3      2
#> 3     1     4      3
#> # ... with 6 more rows


# Get edge information ----
edge_list <-
  tg %>%
  activate(edges) %>%
  data.frame()
edge_list
#>   from to weight
#> 1    1  2      1
#> 2    1  3      2
#> 3    1  4      3
#> 4    2  1      4
#> 5    3  1      5
#> 6    3  2      6
#> 7    4  1      7
#> 8    4  2      8
#> 9    4  3      9
```

But if you also want the names in there as well, here is some code to simply extract the node information as well and join in the data together.

```
# Separate out edges and node data frames
tg_nodes <-
  tg %>%
  activate(nodes) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  rownames_to_column("rowid") %>%
  mutate(rowid = as.integer(rowid))
tg_edges <-
  tg %>%
  activate(edges) %>%
  data.frame()

named_edge_list <-
  tg_edges %>%
  # Rename from nodes
  left_join(tg_nodes, by = c("from" = "rowid")) %>%
  select(-from) %>%  # Remove unneeded column
  rename(from = name) %>%  # Rename column with names now
  
  # Rename to nodes
  left_join(tg_nodes, by = c("to" = "rowid")) %>%
  select(-to) %>%  # Remove unneeded column
  rename(to = name) %>%  # Rename column with names now

  # Cleaning up
  select(from, to, weight)


named_edge_list
#>     from     to weight
#> 1 Hadley  David      1
#> 2 Hadley Romain      2
#> 3 Hadley  Julia      3
#> 4  David Hadley      4
#> 5 Romain Hadley      5
#> 6 Romain  David      6
#> 7  Julia Hadley      7
#> 8  Julia  David      8
#> 9  Julia Romain      9
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I am very grateful not only for the code but also for the illustrative explanation you offer.

Answer (score 6):

Extracting the edges and then joining with the nodes to get the name as in the accepted answer is intuitive but requires a lot of steps.

The approach using `igraph::get.edgelist` (second answer) loses additional information stored in edges (in the question: weight).

Here's a solution that should work.

```
your_tbl_graph %>% 
  activate(edges) %>% 
  mutate(to_name = .N()$name[to], 
         from_name = .N()$name[from]) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(from = from_name, to = to_name, weight)
```

Comment: This is so great! You can also use `%E>%` to shorten this even more instead of doing `activate(edges)`. So it would look like `your_tbl_graph %E>% mutate(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Load package igraph() and apply the function get.edgelist() to the activated edges set. To get a proper output, also apply data.frame() subsequently. You'll get the named edgelist.

```
library(igraph)
edge_list <-
tg %>%
activate(edges) %>%
get.edgelist() %>%
data.frame()
```

Comment: Hi Tom, I found this approach really useful but noted that you lose the attributes of the edges with `get.edgelist()`. But, if you add an extra `%>%` with `cbind(weight = get.edge.attribute(tg, 'weight'))` then I think you arrive to the right answer!

Comment: Thanks, happy to help! Yes, alternatively, you can also simply export the entire edges data.frame with tg %>% activate(edges) %>% as_tibble() and simply cbind() it to the data.frame obtained with get.edgelist(). That way, you'll get all edge attributes in case there are multiple.